# Progress Bar not displayed in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-progressbar

My App has a Splash Activity that shows the App logo to the user while doing some background activities. I am trying to provide a Progress Bar to show the status of the background activities, to let the user wait for few moments.

Activity:

```
    public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ProgressBar simpleProgressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressBar);
doProcessA();
simpleProgressBar.setProgress(10);
doProcessB();
simpleProgressBar.setProgress(20);
..
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:foregroundGravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Splash Activity is themed as follows:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SplashActivity"
  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
</style>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="transparent">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want to show the Progress bar below the app logo. But, I am just not able to get the progress bar to display on the screen.

Comment: try to add this on your `ProgressBar` `android:indeterminate="true"`

Comment: I don't want to show the progress bar to be 'indeterminate'. I want to control the progress based on the processes I am doing.

Comment: so go for `android:visibility="gone"` then if you want to show it just call this `your_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` i think this is what you want to achieve. Hide and show your progressbar. That's why i suggested that you add `indeterminate` so your progress is active and you only need is to hide and show it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

Your need to give the progress bar  timing then, within the time interval do your code what your expecting.

First Initialize the progress bar state(time for progress bar)

```
int progressStatus = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

then inside on create method

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) { 
                progressStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);  // total time for progress bar (milli seconds//
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (progressStatus == 100) {
                 // do your code here //
                } 

            }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be your layout settings, I do not know why you want to set the ProgressBar width to android: layout_width = "match_parent"